# How to match rows that have 2 separately matching columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have 4 columns, A through D. I need to find rows where column C is the same in each row, and column D is the same in each row. It would be best to have a True or False value placed in column E. VBA or a formula works, although I'd think something like this is do-able with a formula.

For example, I have the following:

Row 1   XX    123   XYZ
Row 2   XX    234   XYZ
Row 3   XX    234   YZX
Row 4   XX    234   YZX

In this example, Column E would be False for Rows 1 and 2 and True for Rows 3 and 4.

Comment: What if Row 1 matched Row 3 and Row 2 match Row 4?  What should your output be then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If i = 1 Then
                If .Range("C" & i).Value = .Range("C" & i + 1).Value And _
                .Range("D" & i).Value = .Range("D" & i + 1).Value Then _
                .Range("E" & i).Value = "True" Else .Range("E" & i).Value = "False"
            Else
                If (.Range("C" & i).Value = .Range("C" & i + 1).Value And _
                .Range("D" & i).Value = .Range("D" & i + 1).Value) Or _
                (.Range("C" & i).Value = .Range("C" & i - 1).Value And _
                .Range("D" & i).Value = .Range("D" & i - 1).Value) Then _
                .Range("E" & i).Value = "True" Else .Range("E" & i).Value = "False"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly as requested. Now I actually had a similar issue come about, although slightly more complicated.  

For each matching C cell, check to see if the D cells also match each other. If any D cell doesn't match, then False. Else, True. Example:  
![Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/lHQxH.jpg)

Comment: For that simply paste this formula in Cell E1 `=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C1)<>COUNTIF(D:D,D1),"False","True")` and copy it down

Comment: That seems to just produce the exact same results as your VBA macro. ![screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/a3DxE.jpg)

Comment: I just tested it again. Did you paste the formula in E1? If you pasted it another row then change 1 in the formula to the relevant row Can you also show me all the 4 formulas  that you have in there?

Comment: Do you have `CIT12` somewhere else as well?

Comment: Oh, SHOOT. I didn't think of that: yes, CIT12 appears in other locations. I forgot to mention that things in column D are not exclusive to each entry in Column C.

Comment: Which excel version are you using?

Comment: Try this formula in Cell E1 `=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,C1)=COUNTIFS(C:C, C1,D:D, D1),"True","False")`